# Why is my XmlDocument.Save() failing with "Resource in use by another process"?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

So I need to open an XML document, write to it and then save the file back to disk. Do I need to load the XmlDocument using a filestream to ensure that the stream is closed before saving?

```
 string xmlPath = Server.MapPath("../statedata.xml");
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load(xmlPath);
            XmlNode node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//root/state");
            node.InnerText = string.Format("org.myorg.application.init = {0};",stateJson);
            xmlDocument.Save(xmlPath); //blows up!
```

Comment: It looks like `XmlDocument` keeps the file open(and therefore locked)

Comment: System.Xml is kinda sucky, but it is not *that* bad.  It closes the reader in a finally block.  Clearly the file is in use somewhere else.  Possibly in another web request thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this before. Instead of passing the path directly to Load, create an XmlReader that you can dispose of after the load:

```
string xmlPath = Server.MapPath("../statedata.xml");
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();  
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath)) 
   xmlDocument.Load(reader);         

XmlNode node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//root/state");
node.InnerText = string.Format("org.myorg.application.init = {0};",stateJson);    
xmlDocument.Save(xmlPath); //blows up!
```